# How to print blank character in the Lisp format function?

Tags: lisp, whitespace

I hope there's someone to help me with this, because I can't find any useful answer, and I'm new with Lisp.

What I'm trying to do is to test a value of one element and to print something if its 1, otherwise to print blank character. 
This works when all of the list arguments have the value 1:

```
(defun print-lst (list)
  (format t "~%~a ~a ~a~%"
          (if (= (nth 0 list) '1)
              '¦)
          (if (= (nth 1 list) '1)
              'P)
          (if (= (nth 2 list) '1)
              '¦)))
```

so the output is `¦ P ¦`. But, if the second element in list is 0, it prints NIL on that place `¦ NIL ¦` and I want it to print a space instead `¦   ¦`(not just to skip that character`¦¦`, it is important to there is a blank character in that position in output line if the tested value is not 1).

Is there any way to return a blank character if the condition `(if (= (nth 1 list) '1) 'P)` is not fulfilled or is there any other way to perform this?
I hope I explained that nicely. Thank you.

Comment: You can use `(first list)`, `(second list)` and `(third list)` instead of nth. There is no need to quote atoms like `1` which evaluate to themselves already. Also, perhaps, don't use numeric equality unless you really need it! `(= (third list) 1)` is true not only if `(third list)` contains 1, but also if it contains the floating point value 1.0. Moreover, if if `(third list)` contains a non number, it blows up with an error condition. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Kaz:I am aware of all that. This is something just for a school project, it wont happen that the list arguments contain floating point or non numerical values, only integers 1 or 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`If` takes three arguments: condition, then-form, else-form; the else-form is optional.  Besides, I would use literal character syntax for literal characters.

```
(if (= (nth 0 list) 1)
    #\P
    #\Space)
```

Documentation:

- [Special form `if`](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/speope_if.html#if)
- [Character syntax](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dha.htm)
- [Character names](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/13_ag.htm)

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I was aware of a fact that if statement takes 3 arguments, I just didn't know how to make that space character, but looks like it was pretty easy (I'm newbie with Lisp).

Answer (score 7):

If you want to make full use of the power of `format`, you can use a combination of format conditionals and format GOTO.

Like this:

```
[1]> (format nil "~@{~:[<nothing>~;~:*~A~]~^ ~}" 1 2 nil 4 nil 6)
"1 2 <nothing> 4 <nothing> 6"
```

In your case, this should work:

```
(format t "~&~@{~:[ ~;~:*~A~]~^ ~}"
        ...)
```

This works by doing the following:

1. `~&` inserts a newline unless we're already at the beginning of a line.
2. `~@{...~}` processes the arguments iteratively.
3. `~:[...~;...~]` chooses between the `nil` and non-`nil` case.
4. `~:*` unconsumes the argument that was consumed by `~:[...~]`.
5. `~A` outputs the item being processed.
6. `~^` escapes from the loop on the last iteration (so as not to output an excessive space after the last item).

Comment: This is cool. :)
I use this function for the first time, and now I see it has plenty of options, it's very powerful. :)

Comment: Wow.  Just what I was looking for.  There's no way I would have figured that out on my own.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Counter question:
Do you really need output values that are identifiers ('something) or would also string literals work ("something")?

If the first is true: I suppose it is not possible to use space as an identifier.
If the second is true: use "|", "P" and " " as output values

Comment: @BojanZdravkovic: By the way, you do not need to quote literal forms, as they evaluate to themselves.

Answer (score 0):

[Format is a beast waiting to devour the unwary](http://marcoil.org/archive/170).

That said, it looks like you may want to use some of its higher level directives here. Check out the [Formatted Output](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_c.htm) section of the Lisp Hyperspec, and the [format chapter of PCL](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/a-few-format-recipes.html) (specifically, look at the section that deals with conditional formatting).

Comment: Useful links, I sure will check them out. Thank you.